# Pandas dropna from a subset based on condition

Tags: pandas

What is the most efficient way to dropna for a subset of records based on a condition?

Here's some example data:

```
import numpy as np
d = {'T': [1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2], 'ID': [156, 156, 156, 156, 157, 157, 157, 157],'PMN': [np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan],'XN': [1, np.nan, 5, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

I would like to dropna within column XN when T is 1. I understand how to dropna from a subset, but the condition of T==1 is what's throwing me.

```
df.dropna(axis=0, subset=['XN'], inplace=True)
```

Here's the desired output:

```
out = {'T': [1,1,2,2,2,2], 'ID': [156, 156, 157, 157, 157, 157],'PMN': [np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan],'XN': [1, 5, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan]}
out_df = pd.DataFrame(data=out)
out_df
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's probably easier not to use `dropna`, and just do this by selecting the rows you want:

`out_df = df[(df['T'] != 1) | (~df['XN'].isna())]`

EDIT with more information:

sammywemmy's answer is much clearer here, in my opinion.

Instead of specifying the rows we don't want and dropping them, we are specifying the rows we do want and selecting them.

The rows we don't want are where T is 1 and XN is NA.
sammywemmy writes this as `condition = df['T'].eq(1) & df.XN.isna()` and then selects using `~condition` to invert.

In my original answer, I distributed the negation (`~`) into the formula using DeMorgan's law.

`~(A & B) = (~A | ~B)`.

In English, the translation of "drop where T is 1 and XN is NA" means we need to keep all the rows where T is not 1 and all the rows where XN is not NA.

(Perhaps the trouble you had with sammy's answer was missing the assignment? Since the selection won't happen inplace. `new_df = df.loc[~condition]`)

Comment: Thank you, this achieves what I need. However, I don't quite understand how it works. This selects the rows where T does not equal 1, OR, gives a boolean output of those that aren't na since the ~ is used. That seems the opposite of what I intended, yet it works. Would you mind explaining just a bit more? Many thanks!

Comment: I added some clarification. Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

Create a boolean condition, and filter the dataframe with it :

```py
condition = df['T'].eq(1) & df.XN.isna()
df.loc[~condition]

   T   ID  PMN   XN
0  1  156  NaN  1.0
2  1  156  NaN  5.0
4  2  157  NaN  NaN
5  2  157  NaN  NaN
6  2  157  NaN  NaN
7  2  157  NaN  NaN
```

Comment: This made sense to me, but it's not working for me--the NaNs are still in the t1, XN column.